# Why does this jpeg image render in slightly different colors on different platforms?

Tags: image, jpeg

Our SQA dept. grabbed this random image for testing, and noticed that the color is quite different depending on who does the rendering
[original jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Gmn.jpg)

[Chrome/Chromium (Windows and Linux), MSVC, GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVhzn.png)

[Qt (Windows and Linux), feh (Linux)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOLTe.png)

Searching for an original on the web I found this:
https://www.electricalindia.in/artificial-intelligence-an-advanced-approach-in-power-systems/

Notice that the scaled version used in the article is dark blue:
https://www.electricalindia.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/artificialinteligence-powersystem-696x475.jpg

but their unscaled is lighter blue:
https://www.electricalindia.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/artificialinteligence-powersystem.jpg

Any ideas what's going on with this image?

Comment: Your image has an ICC U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2 profile attached to it which different browsers, OSes and devices treat differently.

Comment: Thanks! Learned something new today...